# Rails ActiveRecord belongs_to with lambda - failing silently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: `Chat` and `ProjectUser` where both models contain `user_id` and `project_id`.

I'm trying to set up a belongs_to relationship between `Chat` and `ProjectUser` with a composite key using a lambda but it fails silently (just returns nil without appearing to run any SQL).

(I'm doing this so I can implement a Chats counter cache on ProjectUsers -- I know I can do this manually but I'd like to use the build-in capability of associations)

```
  belongs_to :project_user, lambda { |chat|
                              unscope(:where).where(project_id: chat.project_id, user_id: chat.user_id)
                            }
```

From `rails c`

```
irb(main):002> chat
=> 
#<Chat:0x0000000114a86118
 id: 43,
...
 user_id: 1,
...
 project_id: 1>

irb(main):003> chat.project_user
=> nil

irb(main):004> ProjectUser.find_by(user_id:1, project_id:1)
  ProjectUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "project_users".* FROM "project_users" WHERE "project_users"."user_id" = ? AND "project_users"."project_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["project_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> 
#<ProjectUser:0x0000000115bed0a0
 id: 1,
 project_id: 1,
 user_id: 1,
...>
```

The other side of the relationship which is a has_many seems to work fine:

```
  has_many :chats, lambda { |project_user|
                     unscope(:where).where(project_id: project_user.project_id, user_id: project_user.user_id)
                   }
```

Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: While this seems best structured for a `has_many :through` relationship. You could simply change `belongs_to` to `has_one` and your code will work appropriately.